# EF Core Tool Ignoring the launchSettings.json in .net core 2.1 and 3.1

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

In launchSettings.json, some variable are defined and application using these variables. When I am running application normally, then environment variables available into the launchSettings.json successfully loaded and app running perfectly. But when I am trying to add migrations, then **ef tool** ignoring the launchSettings.json file.

launchSettings.json looks like

{
"MIN_LOG_LEVEL" : "Warn"
}

Code to read launchSettings.json variables as

```
config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
string logLevel = config["MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] // returing null
```

Some snapshots of code

Program.cs
[image]

launchSettings.json
[image]

Update: I tried with both IIS and Kestrel Server, but in both cases this issue is occurring.

Comment: Are you using IIS or Kestrel?

Comment: @mvermef I am using IIS in both for running the application and for migration also.

Answer (score 6):

After searching a lot regarding this issue, I figure out one thing that really helps me.

The current available **EF Core tools** does not support for the **launchSettings.json** automatically and If we want to get the variables present inside the launchSettings.json, then we **manually** need to parse the file.

The **CLI** added support for launchSettings.json but till now it works only with **dotnet run** command. **EF Core tools** does not have the facility to get the launchSettings.json variable automatically.

This feature will be added soon as I got to know from the [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8695)

if you want to take advantage of the launchSettings.json then you can do it as below.

```
IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Properties", "launchSettings.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();
```